# Need Help Combining Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help combining two queries.  Query 1 looks at a master list of all nodes (Nodes.Caption).  However, the requested data (network traffic) doesn't exist for all nodes.  I would like the combined query to pull the network traffic from the InterfaceTraffic table (See Query 1).  However, if there is not existing data in this table, then pull it from the VIM_VMStatistics table (Query 2).

Query 1

```
SELECT Caption
    ,Round(InAVG, 2) AS NetInAverage_Kbps
    ,Round(InMAX, 2) AS NetInMax_Kbps
    ,Round(OutAVG, 2) AS NetOutAverage_Kbps
    ,Round(OutMAX, 2) AS NetOutMax_Kbps
FROM (
    SELECT caption
        ,nodeid
    FROM Nodes
    ) n
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT nodeid
        ,AVG(In_Averagebps) / 1024 AS InAVG
        ,MAX(In_Maxbps) / 1024 AS InMAX
        ,AVG(Out_Averagebps) / 1024 AS OutAVG
        ,MAX(Out_Maxbps) / 1024 AS OutMAX
    FROM InterfaceTraffic
    WHERE DATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
        AND DATETIME < DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()), 0)
    GROUP BY nodeid
    ) l ON n.NodeID = l.NodeID
ORDER BY Caption
```

---

Query 2

```
SELECT NAME
    ,Round(InAVG, 2) AS NetInAverage_Kbps
    ,Round(InMAX, 2) AS NetInMax_Kbps
    ,Round(OutAVG, 2) AS NetOutAverage_Kbps
    ,Round(OutMAX, 2) AS NetOutMax_Kbps
FROM (
    SELECT NAME
        ,VirtualMachineID
            ,NodeID
    FROM VIM_VirtualMachineNodes
    ) n
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT VirtualMachineID
        ,AVG(AvgNetworkReceiveRate) AS InAVG
        ,MAX(MaxNetworkReceiveRate) AS InMAX
        ,AVG(AvgNetworkTransmitRate) AS OutAVG
        ,MAX(MaxNetworkTransmitRate) AS OutMAX
    FROM VIM_VMStatistics
    WHERE DATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
        AND DATETIME < DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()), 0)
    GROUP BY VirtualMachineID
    ) l ON n.VirtualMachineID = l.VirtualMachineID
```

Comment: *Please* preview your post before submitting...

Comment: what is the relationship between caption, nodeid, name, virtualmachineid -- if there is no relationship there is no way to combine them.  You didn't tell us the relationship -- we would need that to be able to combine them.

Comment: I forgot to add that nodeid does exists for both the Nodes table and the VIM_VirtualMachineNodes.  However, nodeid does not exist for vim_vimstatistics.  This table only contains the virtualmachineid

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for these cute little sub-selects.  This will work exactly the same

```
SELECT n.Caption
    ,Round(InAVG, 2) AS NetInAverage_Kbps
    ,Round(InMAX, 2) AS NetInMax_Kbps
    ,Round(OutAVG, 2) AS NetOutAverage_Kbps
    ,Round(OutMAX, 2) AS NetOutMax_Kbps
FROM Nodes n
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT nodeid
        ,AVG(In_Averagebps) / 1024 AS InAVG
        ,MAX(In_Maxbps) / 1024 AS InMAX
        ,AVG(Out_Averagebps) / 1024 AS OutAVG
        ,MAX(Out_Maxbps) / 1024 AS OutMAX
  FROM InterfaceTraffic
  WHERE DATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
    AND DATETIME < DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()), 0)
  GROUP BY nodeid
) l ON n.NodeID = l.NodeID
ORDER BY Caption

SELECT n.NAME
    ,Round(InAVG, 2) AS NetInAverage_Kbps
    ,Round(InMAX, 2) AS NetInMax_Kbps
    ,Round(OutAVG, 2) AS NetOutAverage_Kbps
    ,Round(OutMAX, 2) AS NetOutMax_Kbps
FROM VIM_VirtualMachineNodes n 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT VirtualMachineID
        ,AVG(AvgNetworkReceiveRate) AS InAVG
        ,MAX(MaxNetworkReceiveRate) AS InMAX
        ,AVG(AvgNetworkTransmitRate) AS OutAVG
        ,MAX(MaxNetworkTransmitRate) AS OutMAX
  FROM VIM_VMStatistics
  WHERE DATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
    AND DATETIME < DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()), 0)
  GROUP BY VirtualMachineID
) l ON n.VirtualMachineID = l.VirtualMachineID
```

I'm going to assume that VIM_VirtualMachineNodes has a nodeid field like Nodes

---

There are a number of ways to do this, this is the way I think is clearest....

First you need a list of nodeids that matter.

```
SELECT DISTINCT nodeid 
FROM (
  SELECT nodeid from nodes
  UNION ALL
  SELECT nodeid from VIM_VirtualMachineNodes
) as node_list
```

Now we left join this to our two lists and select the items using coalesce

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(l1.nodeid, l2.nodeid, 0) as nodeid,
  COALESCE(l1.InAVG,  l2.InAVE, 0.0) AS NetInAverage_Kbps,
  COALESCE(l1.InMAX,  l2.InMAX, 0.0) AS NetInMax_Kbps,
  COALESCE(l1.OutAVG, l1.OutAVG, 0.0) AS NetOutAverage_Kbps,
  COALESCE(l1.OutMAX, l1.OutMAX, 0.0) AS NetOutMax_Kbps
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT nodeid 
  FROM (
    SELECT nodeid from nodes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nodeid from VIM_VirtualMachineNodes
  ) as node_list
) as N
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT nodeid
        ,AVG(In_Averagebps) / 1024 AS InAVG
        ,MAX(In_Maxbps) / 1024 AS InMAX
        ,AVG(Out_Averagebps) / 1024 AS OutAVG
        ,MAX(Out_Maxbps) / 1024 AS OutMAX
  FROM InterfaceTraffic
  WHERE DATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
    AND DATETIME < DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()), 0)
  GROUP BY nodeid
) l1 ON n.NodeID = l1.NodeID
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT nodeid
        ,AVG(AvgNetworkReceiveRate) AS InAVG
        ,MAX(MaxNetworkReceiveRate) AS InMAX
        ,AVG(AvgNetworkTransmitRate) AS OutAVG
        ,MAX(MaxNetworkTransmitRate) AS OutMAX
  FROM VIM_VMStatistics
  WHERE DATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
    AND DATETIME < DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, getdate()), 0)
  GROUP BY VirtualMachineID
) l2 ON n.NodeID = l2.NodeID
```

As you can see I did not bother with the name, but you can join to those in the sub-query if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a query on Nodes with left outer joins to the query1 and query2. For simplicity, we assume that:

1. You have views for Query1 and Query2
2. That Query1 and Query2 return at most one row per node caption

Then the query look like this:

```
SELECT caption,
       (CASE WHEN Q1.Caption IS NULL THEN Q2.NetInAverage_Kbps
             ELSE Q1.NetInAverage_Kbps END) AS NetInAverage_Kpbs,
       (CASE WHEN Q1.Caption IS NULL THEN Q2.NetInMax_Kbps
             ELSE Q1.NetInMax_Kbps END) AS NetInMax_Kbps,
       (CASE WHEN Q1.Caption IS NULL THEN Q2.NetOutAverage_Kbps
             ELSE Q1.NetOutAverage_Kbps END) AS NetOutAverage_Kbps,
       (CASE WHEN Q1.Caption IS NULL THEN Q2.NetOutMax_Kbps
             ELSE Q1.NetOutAverage_Kbps END) AS NetOutMax_Kbps
FROM Nodes N
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Query1 Q1 ON N.Caption=Q1.Caption
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Query2 Q2 ON N.Caption=Q2.Name
```

This query checks if there is a row found in Query1, if not, Query2 is used, else Query1.